# Angular Display JSON data after button click

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

Display Json data when a button is being clicked and make a certain element display the Json data.

**RESULT:**

result of code:

[image]

**TS:**

```
import UsersJson from '../../assets/users.json'; //Json file location
    
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
    
      getUsers(special:any):void{
    
      special.innerText = JSON.stringify(UsersJson).replace(/,|}|{|\\/g, "\n");
                  
          constructor() { }
        
          ngOnInit(): void { }
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <button (click)="getUsers(lblName)">Show All Users</button>
  </div>

    <pre #lblName></pre>
```

**Full documentation on my GitHub** https://github.com/LearAdini/AngularJsonPipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Angular built-in `json` pipe as :

```html
{{ value_expression | json }}
```

[JsonPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) API doc

---

**Example:**

HTML file:

```html
<button (click)="getUsers()">Show All Users</button>

<h4 *ngIf="users">{{ users | json }}</h4>
```

UsersComponent class:

```ts
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  users: any;

  getUsers() {
    // fetch the json data and assign it to -> this.users
  }
}
```

Comment: @BeatrixKiddo I have edited the answer with an example. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: THANK YOU Siddhant !, so what I did that work, assigned the UsersJson to this.users and display the data when a button is being clicked:                   
getUsers():void {
    this.users = UsersJson;
  }